# С чем связано ограничение названия переменной в 251 byte в Perl?

Tags: perl

Это ограничение операционной системы или самого Perl? И можно ли на это как-то влиять?

Comment: думаю, оно ограничено здравым смыслом. В первых бейсиках вообще было 2 символа и как то жили.

Comment: @KoVadim почему именно 251, а не например 255?)

Comment: это очевидно. 251+4+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ограничение самого perl
Источник: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html